# MS Word add-in Content Controls with button-like trigger for Dialog

Tags: ms-word, office365, office-js, word-addins

I am developing an MS Word add-in using word JavaScript API. My use case is that I allow the user insert table, but the table is wrapped with `Content Control` with the `cannotEdit` flag set to true. So the table inside the document is only read-only and editing happens only through a separate dialog, that is supposed to be opened by clicking a button below the table.

After digging through the documentation I couldn't find any relevant info regarding inserting buttons into the document. What is my best bet then, what could be the workaround? Could OOXML help here somehow?

Comment: The problem would be that there is no communication between controls on the document surface and the Office JS APIs. The button would need to be in the Ribbon or the Office JS taskpane.

Comment: Thank you Cindy. I was thinking that maybe I could put a button-like image (png) below the table and add Binding to this, together with an event handler for selection change of that image.